# Rails HABTM or has_many?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, relational-database

I have two models: Person, and Property.  In the Person model I have a field which stores the role of the person(tenant, owner, admin, contractor, etc).  Since each property will belong to an owner and potentially have one or more tenants, I thought this would be a good opportunity to use the HABTM model relation.

Do I have this right?

Also, how do I reference the attached model?  Assuming my join model is named PropertiesPeople, and I wanted to fetch the tenants for a particular property, would that be the following?

```
@property.people.where(:role => "tenant")
```

Comment: You have the option of using either HABTM or has_many through. I generally like to use has_many through as it has the flexibility of adding extra attributes in its own table in the db. To query, its better to do it this way to avoid sql injection: `@property.people.where("role = ?", "tenant")`

Comment: @forthowin your tip about rewriting the query to avoid sql injection is bogus. Rails will do the exact same sanitation if you pass a hash to `where`. Plus he is not even using an parameter in the query.  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the same Person can have more than one Property, you should can use HABTM. Something like this:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  # in the people table you are storing the 'role' value
  has_and_belongs_to_many :properties, join_table: 'people_properties'
end

class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :people, join_table: 'people_properties'
end
```

You should create the intermidiate table `people_properties` with the foreign keys, `person_id` and `property_id`.

The problem of this approach is that if a Person can be "tenant" in one property and "contractor" in another, for example, you can't store that information. In that case I will suggest using an intermidiate model, like this

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :property_people
    has_many :properties, through: :property_people
end

class PropertyPerson
    # now you store here the 'role' value
    belongs_to :person
    belongs_to :property
end

class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :property_people
    has_many :people, through: :property_people
end
```

I don't know for sure if the class names are successfully inferred from the relationships names, in that case you can always indicate `class_name` or even the `foreign_key` for the associations. Also you can indicate the table for a model, using `self.table_name=`

Comment: can you give some more detail about how to accomplish this?  It seems like this is essentially the same concept behind HABTM.

Comment: From the code point of view HABTM is translated by Rails into `has_many ..., through: ....` (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/0af3dd4438047d8c5783dff1cfcf9c696b44bdff/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations.rb#L1720). So it is probably a bit better to use the `has_many :through` way directly.

Comment: Thanks for your great update, one quick question: If I were to store the role within PropertyPerson, how would I reference it?  Also, why does PropertyPerson not inherit from ActiveRecord::Base?